# DatePickerDialog open the current date

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I have put the DatePickerDialog on edittext and it always opens the current date.

But i want to open my custom date:

```
  edt_dob.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                BdayDatePickerDialog.show();
            }
        });


 private void setDateTimeField() {

        Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        BdayDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                edt_dob.setText(dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime()));


            }

        }, newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

    }
```

From above code it shows always the current date . but i want to set my own custom date.

How can i set it to custom date ?

Comment: Did you look at the documentation for DatePickerDialog?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation

```
DatePickerDialog(Context context, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth)
```

Creates a new date picker dialog for the specified date using the parent context's default date picker dialog theme.

So, in your code  if you want date to be 10-09-2016
supply

2016,9,10 ) instead of

```
newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
```

Answer (score 0):

You instantiate calendar picker with default callendar date, which is current day.
You should put your date that you want to show in instance, the bottom line.

```
BdayDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
            newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
            edt_dob.setText(dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime()));


        }

    }, yourYear, yourMonth, yourDay);
```